# file_get_contents returns false on existing readable file

Tags: php, apache, file-io

Well, I'm starting to hate PHP. I have a file, which is perfectly readable (is_readable returns true), has 777 permission, is normally opened by fopen, but file_get_contents is returning false.
The code is following:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
$handle = fopen("tres.txt","w+");
try{
$cnt = file_get_contents("/var/www/tres.txt");
}
catch(Exception $err){ echo $err->getMessage(); }
if ($handle) echo "Allright!", "<br />";
if ($cnt) echo "Good";
if(is_readable("/var/www/tres.txt")) echo " Is";
?>
```

And even though I turned on all error reporting options I knew, no errors are catched, and that drives me mad. Changing file path to "./tres.txt" of "tres.txt" has no effect either.
Where the problem may lie?

P.S. It's run on PHP5 and apache2.

Comment: You already opened it with fopen then you try to open it again with file_get_contents... probably blocking it because it's already in use. Read its contents, THEN you can open it for writing.

Comment: Is `display_errors` set to `on` ?

Comment: Not the issue, but the `if` should have checked for `strlen($cnt)` rather.

Comment: @Pekka Oh, crap. It's not actually. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan Grossman Laconic and helpful. You should have put it as an answer so I could accept it =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fopen("tres.txt","w+");` truncates the file. Reading it right after that makes no sense.

`$cnt` is most likely not false but the empty string `''` which is considered `false` in a boolean context.

`if ($cnt !== false) echo "Good";` would probably output "Good".

Comment: But `file_get_contents` should return empty string then, not false.

Comment: It does. but an empty string is false in a boolean context. Try `var_dump($cnt);`

Comment: Yes, file_get_contents should return false if it fails to read the file (file does not exists or is locked by the FileSystem) but will return empty string if the file is empty. So ThiefMaster posted the correct answer with very good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use `fopen` when using `file_get_contents`. Remove `fopen`.

Comment: Especially since his fopen call *truncates* the file.